# Text based document preparation system for media rich publications

Tags: html, css, desktop-publishing

I have recently been doing a fair amount of desktop publishing with Microsoft Publisher, but coming from development of HTML/CSS sites I can't stand the lack of alignment options and would feel much more comfortable using a text-based publishing solution. Ideally, the solution would include a CSS grid system style 'gutter' for content in a more standard grid but I would still, of course, need to be able to have absolute positioned content.

I know I could just use HTML/CSS but was wondering if there are any better solutions (or maybe a HTML/CSS library for print?). I have looked at LaTeX and while it looks great for mainly text-based documents it seems to fall short with lots of media/layout options.

I would need to be able to create and apply complex formatting to:

- Text boxes.
- Captioned images.
- Tables (ideally with complex layout options).

It would also be great to be able to annotate design drawings with arrows, though this may not be possible in any text-based solutions.

Maybe Publisher is the best solution for me at this point, but I am constantly frustrated with it and running into performance issues on large (20+A3 pages) media-rich documents leading to data loss.

If anyone has any recommendations I would be very grateful.

Many thanks, Dom

Comment: What is your target file type? Is it PDF (of so which version), PostScript or Latex, something else that your printers prefer if you are using professional print shops? http://resources.printhandbook.com/pages/file-types.php has quite a nice summary of some of the issues.

Comment: @SteveBarnes Ideally PDF 2.0, sorry for not mentioning.